# Mocking a singleton c# class in nunit

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, nunit, moq, sealed

I have a class, something like this:-

```
namespace CalendarIntegration.Google
{
    public sealed class GoogleSyncEventProcessor : ICalendarSyncEventProcessor
    {

public void ProcessEventRequest(object events, int soUserId, string calendarId, bool addLogs = false)
        {
            if (GoogleWatchManager.Instance.IsGoogleTwoWaySynLive)
            {
```

GoogleWatchManager is further a sealed class.

```
namespace CalendarIntegration.Google
{
    public sealed class GoogleWatchManager
    {
        readonly bool isGoogleTwoWaySyncLive = true;
        public GoogleWatchManager()
        {
                   isGoogleTwoWaySyncLive = false;
        }

 virtual public bool IsGoogleTwoWaySynLive
        {
            get { return isGoogleTwoWaySyncLive; }
        }
```

I want fake/mock GoogleWatchManager class and make the value of `GoogleWatchManager.Instance.IsGoogleTwoWaySynLive` in the nunit test cases, by default it is true in GoogleWatchManager class.

I tried the below but it doesn't work-

```
using EFBL;
using NUnit.Framework;
using EFBL.CalendarIntegration.CalendarSync;
using EFBL.CalendarIntegration.Google;
using Moq;

namespace EFBL.CalendarIntegration.Google
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class GoogleSyncEventProcessorSpec
    {
        public GoogleSyncEventProcessor google;
        public GoogleWatchManager googleManager;

        public void SetUp()
        {
        }

        [Test]
        public void ProcessEventRequest_NoEvents_ExceptionThrown()
        {
            var mock = new Mock<GoogleWatchManager>();
            mock.SetupGet(foo => foo.IsGoogleTwoWaySynLive).Returns(true);
            //             watch.Setup(i => i.IsGoogleTwoWaySynLive).Returns(false);
            // var mock = new Mock<GoogleWatchManager>().Object;
            GoogleSyncEventProcessor obj = GoogleSyncEventProcessor.Instance;

            obj.ProcessEventRequest(null, -1, "");
            //            isGoogleTwoWaySyncLive
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you in control of the classes in the example? if so then you need to encapsulate behind an abstraction that you control and then mock and inject into the dependent class. Classes should also depend on abstractions and not on concretions or implementation concerns.

Comment: @Nkosi Do you have any example? I am a newbie in .net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:-

```
using System;
using EFBL;
using NUnit.Framework;
using TypeMock.ArrangeActAssert;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace EFBL.CalendarIntegration.Google
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class GoogleSyncEventProcessorSpec
    {
        public GoogleSyncEventProcessor googleSync;
        public GoogleWatchManager googleManager;

        [SetUp]
        public void Init() {
            googleManager = Isolate.Fake.Instance<GoogleWatchManager>();
            googleSync = GoogleSyncEventProcessor.Instance;
        }

        [Test]
        public void RequiresThatTwoWaySyncLiveBeFalse()
        {
            Isolate.NonPublic.Property.WhenGetCalled(googleManager, "IsGoogleTwoWaySynLive").WillReturn(false);
            Assert.AreEqual(false, googleManager.IsGoogleTwoWaySynLive);
        }
```